# How does Scala implement the addition operator behind the scenes?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, operators

In Scala, the **+** operator is actually a method called **+** implemented by objects. In the case of **Int**, from [Int.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala):

```scala
/** Returns the sum of this value and `x`. */
def +(x: Int): Int
```

And 1-arity methods with no side-effects can be called using an [infix notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html):

```scala
// this
caller method callee
// and this
caller.method(callee)
// are identical, so
1 + 2
// is actually
(1).+(2)
```

But I can't find on **Int.scala** how the language actually performs the integer addition inside the **+** method.

How is it done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compiler magic. The compiler translates into the intrinsic "iadd" instruction on the JVM.

```
class Test {

  def first(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y

  def second(x: Int, y: Int) = (x).+(y)
}
```

Which compiles down to exactly what you'd hope for in either case

```
$ javap -c Test.class
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public class Test {
  public int first(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: iadd
       3: ireturn

  public int second(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: iadd
       3: ireturn

 public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #20                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Similar things happen with other JVM primitive operations

If you implement "+" on your own class, it's just dispatched into a normal method call

```
class Test2 {
  def +(t2: Test2) = "whatever"

  def test = this + this
}
```

Becomes

```
$ javap -c Test2.class
Compiled from "Test2.scala"
public class Test2 {
  public java.lang.String $plus(Test2);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #12                 // String whatever
       2: areturn

  public java.lang.String test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_0
       2: invokevirtual #19                 // Method $plus:(LTest2;)Ljava/lang/String;
       5: areturn

  public Test2();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #23                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Notice the method is named "$plus." That's because "+" isn't a valid method name as far as the JVM is concerned. Other symbols that aren't valid JVM names have similar translations.

In all these cases, scalac uses the static type to determine wether to emit a method call or a JVM primitive.

The actual determination is made in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/icode/GenICode.scala , a phase that happens very late in the compiler's chain. For the most part all previous phases treat x + y as if it's going to be a method call regardless of x's type.